# Ajax to Spring MVC Controller and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, modelandview

Here's the desired flow that I am looking for :

1. Large data (table) is passed to Spring Controller through a javascript function.
2. Controller processes the data.
3. Controller returns a new ModelAndView
4. Render this new ModelAndView on the screen.

I am trying to send data to controller using an Ajax call. However, the returned modelandview ends up as a response to the ajax call, and as a result does not get rendered on the screen.

Is there a away I can avoid this behavior. Or perhaps, an approach to achieve the flow I am looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for something similar to this as well, unfortunately I had to use jQuery and that Ajax response to change the data. I do not believe you can do what you want without a page refresh. Assuming you are using Java, the model is rendered to the view server side before loading on the client side. (I am fairly new to MVC, so I may be wrong, if there is another solution, I want to hear it as well).

Comment: If I just invoke the controller method mapping url on the browser (that is, not use an ajax call), the new ModelAndView gets rendered like a charm. But ofcourse, in this case, I have not passed my data to the controller. So I'm basically looking for a way to pass the data to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refresh the whole page, using AJAX doesn't bring any advantage.

If you only want to refresh some part of the page, then you need to provide a JavaScript callback function that will use the AJAX response, and modify the DOM of the current page.